# need help for web service

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, integration

```
global class creatorder {
  global class batchwrapper {
webservice List<Batch__c> child   {get;set;}
    webservice List<Quote_line_Item__c> data {get;set;}
    webservice  List<batch__c> finalbatch=new List<batch__c>() ;
    webservice List<batchwrapper> batch {get;set;}
   transient webservice string quoteId{get;set;}
    webservice String imageURL{get;set;}
    webservice String date1{get;set;}
    webservice String date2{get;set;}
    webservice String date3{get;set;}
    webservice String date4{get;set;}
    webservice String date5{get;set;}
    webservice String date6{get;set;}
    webservice String inputvalue{get;set;}
    set<id> qId;
        webservice Quote_Line_Item__c q {get;set;}
        webservice List<batch__c> batch1 {get;set;}

        global batchwrapper(){

            q = new Quote_Line_Item__c();
            batch1 = new List<batch__c>();
        }
  }

  webService static batchwrapper order(batchwrapper bw1) {
         quoteId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');                
               qId = new set<id>();
                finalbatch=new List<batch__c>();
                Quote__c quo = [Select id,Generated__c,isEdited__c,isPreviewd__c,Gen_Num__c,Quote_Number_New__c from Quote__c where Id=:quoteId];
               data =[Select id,Name,Client_P_N__c,Description__c,Comments__c,LastModifiedDate ,Other_Lead_Time__c,Standard_Estimated_Lead_Time__c,Quote_Validity__c,Terms_Conditions__c from Quote_Line_Item__c where Quote1__c=: quo.Id order by CreatedDate] ;                
                for(Quote_Line_Item__c q :data ){
                 qId.add(q.Id);
                  }
        batch = new List<batchwrapper> ();
        finalbatch=[select id, confirm_Order__c,Unit_Price__c,MOD_Maxi__c,Unit_Price_Text__c,Sign_for_max_Quantity__c,Quantity_Text__c,LeadTime__c,Other_Lead_Time__c,Max_quantity_Pdf__c,Quantity__c,Max_Quantity__c,Asked_Qty__c, Sub_Unit_Price__c,Quote_Line_Item__c  from Batch__c  where Quote_Line_Item__c  in :qId ORDER BY Quantity__c asc];
        for(Quote_Line_Item__c q:data ){
            batchwrapper bw =  new batchwrapper();
            bw.q = q != null ? q : null;
            bw.batch1 = finalbatch != null ? finalbatch : null;
            batch.add(bw);  
            return batchwrapper;    
        }
  }
}
```

i need to get data from salesforce to other app using webservice any help will with this code will be greatly appreciated

error:

> Error Error: createorder Compile Error: Variable does not exist: quoteId at line 28 column 10

I am very new to webservice .converting my apex class to webservice apex code  .
help me ....[image]

Comment: Why do you use the `transient` keyword to define the `quoteId` in your wrapper class?

Answer (score 1):

The compile error you quote occurs because the `quoteId` field of the `batchwrapper` class can only be referenced via an instance of the class like this:

```
batchwrapper bw =  new batchwrapper();
bw.quoteId = ...;
```

If you need a variable to keep the value in within the static `order` method declare a local variable for that (and any other short-lived variables you need):

```
webService static batchwrapper order(batchwrapper bw1) {
    String quoteId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    ...
```

Only fields that you need to pass into and out of the web service should be declared as fields of the `batchwrapper` class.